# How to override mod_security rule variable

Tags: apache-httpd, modsecurity

We have the following mod_security rule which is loaded globally on the server:

```
SecAction "id:219000,phase:2,pass,setvar:'tx.xmlrpc_watch_period=300',setvar:'tx.xmlrpc_requests_limit=5',setvar:'tx.xmlrpc_block_timeout=600',nolog"
```

I would like to be able to override the `tx.xmlrpc_requests_limit` value for a specific domain via the domain's Apache vhost configuration file. Something like this:

```
setvar:'tx.xmlrpc_requests_limit=10
```

I have tried using the full action line as below but this did not override the setting:

```
SecAction "id:219000,phase:2,pass,setvar:'tx.xmlrpc_watch_period=300',setvar:'tx.xmlrpc_requests_limit=10',setvar:'tx.xmlrpc_block_timeout=600',nolog"
```

What is the syntax for locally overriding the `tx.xmlrpc_requests_limit` variable above for a single domain?